# Multi object drag

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitouch

While dragin multi objects using the following code the the object is shaking when i touch the object,

```
   -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
    {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == img1)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        img1.center = location;
        return;
    }
    if (touch.view == img2)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        img2.center = location;
        return;
    }
    }
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
     }
```

What is problem in my code, is there any other method to drag and if the view contain one more object?please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are talking about more object to drag all at once then you should remove the return from you touch begain method

Comment: im having mutilple objects but i drag one at a time, While remove tat retun also it not working propely,